# QT Creator compile Non-QT project with VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, qt-creator

I'm trying to use VC++ (from Visual Studio 2012) to complile projects from QT Creator 2.8. I try to create Non-QT project in QT Creator [image: Non-QT project creation]
I see it says that it would be "CMake build".
After some steps (name of project, version control...) is shows this message:

[image]

I have this kit detected:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? I have a CMake 2.8.11.2 installed.
I know that I can use MinGW, but I need both x32 and x64 compilers, as well as C++11 support (, nullptr, auto and so on). I know, that CMake can generate VS's project files for me, but what if i need to compile them rather often? Creating *.sln and then opening it in VS, and then compilong it for needed platform seems a bit irrational for me. Or maybe there is another compiler that suits my needs (x32, x64, C++11)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VC's compiler with cmake projects just fine. Use the "NMake Makefiles" generator and build your project by invoking `nmake`. A further improvement (at least for large projects) would be to use `jom`, by using the generator "NMake Makefiles JOM".

Comment: As I can see, I currently use jom (at 'build events' there is a message from it). Thank you, I'll try to find what to do with it

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Qt Creator and the problem in the question: Qt Creator not using the kit shown.

Comment: @rubenvb: It does answer the question in the last paragraph though: "what if i need to compile them rather often?"

Comment: @rubenvb And so, how to make QT Creator to use the kit shown?

Comment: @Ivan: I don't know that. But accepting an answer that doesn't answer your question isn't going to help it get answered `;-)`